# Нужны советы по использованию имен аргументов функций, которые описаны во внешнем окружении

Tags: python

Проблема следующая, и думаю известная многим. При использовании в именах аргументов функций переменных с названиями, которые использовались во внешнем окружении IDE выводим соответствующее предупреждение - Shadow name "proxy" from outer scope. И правильно делает, так как это может привести к ошибкам(обсуждается вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125172/10230655))

```
proxy = 'somepr.ox'

def func(proxy):
    # do somethings
    return proxy
```

Ни использовать решение которое вытекает из [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)(синонимы или proxy_ ) мне не очень нравится так все равно иногда можно допустить ошибку, да и код выглядит убого(имхо):

def func(proxy_, server_, user_):
    ...
    return proxy_

Один знакомый(*Megabit, привет*) дал совет который я использовал в C++ - в начале каждого аргумента ставится буква А(Аргумент), но в Python используется другой стиль и такой "финт" наверное испортит читабельность кода.

```
int BrootSearch(byte* Abuff, int ALength)
{
    int result = -1;
}
```

Прошу совет у людей кто работает в команде или много работал с чужим кодом и знает хороший метод именования аргументов которых удобен для чтения кода.
Спасибо за внимание. [Вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008745/10230655) описанный ниже, предлагаю не рассматривать:

```
def func(proxy):
    return proxy

def main():
    proxy = 'somepr.ox'

main()
```

Comment: ну если так делает большинство, может в PEP8 предложить)))

Comment: Почему проблема решается именно в таком направлении? Может, это внешняя переменная должна называться по-другому? Как минимум, глобальные переменные должны называться сложнее, а для аргументов функций наоборот логичны простые названия.

Comment: Я специально выбрал proxy, и как то не хочется его называть proxyserver, например, ведь python лаконичный язык

Comment: Я еще раз повторюсь, синонимы или другие усложнения названия не очень хороший вариант лично для меня.

Comment: @garrythehotdog, назовите её `cfg_proxy`, если она глобальная. Если это переменная для замыкания и внешняя по отношению к функции внутри функции, то у вас даже с префиксом все равно получатся одинаковые названия.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov если честно, то вариант с main тогда выглядит куда изящней.

Answer (score 1):

Можно параметры функции спрятать за `**`, но мне это видится диким костылем:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    return kwargs['proxy'], kwargs['name']

proxy = 'somepr.ox'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(func(proxy='www.ru', name='abc'))
```

---

**PS.**

Можно, конечно, сократить название параметра до `_`, но это уже костыль для костыля:

```
def func(**_):
    return _['proxy'], _['name']
```

Comment: не, в ущерб читаемости кода уж точно не стоит

Comment: я думаю для новичков такой код будет совсем отталкивающим

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой псевдокод от бизнес-консультанта ))

```
if  вы_работаете_в_команде :
    if  ответ_отсутствует_в_задокументированных_внутренних_соглашениях_по_стилю_кода
        обсудите этот пункт в команде
        добавьте нужный пункт во внутренние соглашения
    поступайте по внутренним соглашениям
else:
    используйте PEP8 (т.е. пишите: proxy_ )
```

Тогда другие вас поймут при чтении вашего кода. Если пишете только для себя и не планируете работать в команде - то какая разница.

Answer (score 0):

То что вам по-советовали на мой взгляд ничем не отличается от нижнего подчёркивания: `Aurl` и `url_`.

Я бы вам посоветовал перевести все входные параметры в словари или объекты со значением словарь или кортеж.
Тогда бы у вас аргументы назывались текстом на входе и как переменная в функциях, ну и распаковка облегчит жизнь:

```
my_args = {"x" : 10}

def f(x):
    return x*2

print f(**my_args)
```